# добавление записи в json с помощью python

Tags: python, json

Понимаю, что вопрос простой, но не пойму как дописать в json. Есть json:

```
{
  "name": "Вася",
  "phone": "123456789"
}
```

и код:

```
import json

name = input("Имя: ")
phone = input("Телефон: ")

def create_json():
    json_data = {
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
    }
    with open('db.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

# create_json()

def add_to_json():
    json_data = {
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
    }
    data = json.load(open("db.json"))
    data.append(json_data)
    with open("db.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

add_to_json()
```

Вылезает ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Нужно добавить запись, что бы json имел такой вид:

```
{
  "name": "Вася",
  "phone": "123456789"
},
{
  "name": "Вася",
  "phone": "123456789"
}
```

Comment: `что бы json имел такой вид:` - это некорректный json. Чтобы записать несколько словарей в json, их нужно положить в список.

Comment: спасибо, теперь все получилось

Comment: Если получилось, можно добавить свое решение ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было добавить `[]` при создании `json` файла, итоговый код:

```
import json

name = input("Имя: ")
phone = input("Телефон: ")

def create_json():
    json_data = [{
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
    }
    ]
    with open('db.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

# create_json()

def add_to_json():
    json_data = {
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
    }
    data = json.load(open("db.json"))
    data.append(json_data)
    with open("db.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

add_to_json()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def add_to_json():
    json_data = {
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
    }
   
    with open("db.json", "a") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        file.write(',\n')    
add_to_json()
```